# Assign results of a command to a variable while checking results of said command

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to combine the following loop:

```
while ps -p PID_OF_JAVA_PROCESS; do
    sleep 1;
done;
```

Into the following loop:

```
if pgrep -f java.*name_of_file > /dev/null; then
    echo "Shutting down java process!"
    pkill -f java.*name_of_file
else
    echo "Not currently running!"
fi
```

By assigning the results of pgrep into a variable (the PID of this java process) -- like something along the following:

```
if pgrep -f java.*name_of_file > /dev/null; then
    echo "Our java process is currently running!"
    pkill -f java.*name_of_file
    echo "Please wait while our process shuts down!"
    while ps -p $(pgrep -f java.*name_of_file); do
        sleep 1;
    done;
else
    echo "Not currently running!"
fi
```

I would like to combine the above while keeping the results of each command quiet (except echo, of course).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if pids=${pgrep -f java.*name_of_file 2>/dev/null }; then
    echo "Our java process is currently running!"
    kill -f $pids  > /dev/null 2>&1
    echo "Please wait while our process shuts down!"
    while ps -p $(pgrep -f java.*name_of_file 2> /dev/null); do
        sleep 1;
    done;
else
    echo "Not currently running!"
fi
```

`> /dev/null` redirects stdout to /dev/null

`2> /dev/null` redirects stderr to /dev/null

`> /dev/null 2>&1` redirects stderr to stdout to /dev/null, thus silencing the command whatsoever

If I assume your two scripts above run right, this slightly modified version should be what you want :)

Comment: Got it~ Is it possible to get our PID from the first comparison (insert into a variable) and reuse it in the while loop or should I keep as is (no real benefit)?

Comment: You can use `if pids=$(pgrep -f 'java.*name_of_file'); then ...; kill $pids;`

Comment: @thatotherguy Thank you for the follow up -- I will give that a try!